# NMinimize negating the minimum value

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am having a very strange issue. I have the following piece of code:

```
ee = 0.685149/(1 - E^-l) 
Plot[ee, {l, 1.8, 10}]
NMinimize[{ee, 1.8 <= l <= 10}, l]
```

As can be seen from the plot, the function is decreasing and is minimized at $l=10$. Mathematica indeed finds the correct minimizer, but the value is negated:

`{-0.685181, {l -> 10.}}`

I am very confused why the value is negated. Any idea?

```
ee /. l -> 10
0.685181
```

Version: "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"

[image]

Comment: Update: When I add `Method -> NelderMead` to NMinimize, it works fine, so it seems "Automatic" is buggy somehow?

Comment: v12.2.0 on Win7-x64 does not show the negation. Please add the output of `$Version` to your post.

Comment: v13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023) works as expected

Comment: Here is the version: 

"13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)". Perhaps I'll update to 13.2 and try again.

Comment: OK in 13.2 on Windows 10.